# Better way to calculate two arithmetic progressions?

Tags: c++, c++11

As part of a C++ 2d histogram class, I have to calculate a vector of bins for x and y values. Here's how I'm doing it;

```
    double xInc = (xMax - xMin)/xBins;
    double yInc = (yMax - yMin)/yBins;
    for(int i = 0; i<(xBins+1); i++){ m_xVals[i] = xMin + i*xInc; }
    for(int i = 0; i<(yBins+1); i++){ m_yVals[i] = yMin + i*yInc; }
```

Am I missing something in `algorithms` that could do this more succinctly? Alternately, is there a way to turn this into 1 loop without it being overrun with control statements?

Comment: unless xbins and ybins have the same values, you don't really want to combine the loops. you CAN have multiple increments/conditions in a loop, but as soon as the "smallest" of the two finishes, the other one will be terminated as well, and you'll end up with missing bin initializations.

Comment: @MarcB That's why I'm asking the question. This seems like a common enough situation, so I wonder if there is a smart hack out there. In general xBins and yBins will not be equal.

Comment: You could find `loopCondition = min(xBins+1, yBins+1)`, and then `int i=0; for(; i < loopCondition; ++i){//update m_xVals[i]; //update m_yVals[i]}` and then `for(; i < xBins+1; ++i){//update m_xVals[i]};` followed by `for(; i < yBins+1; ++i){//update m_yVals[i]}` 3 for loops to replace 2, but the first would overlap the computations as much as possible. I doubt it would really make a difference.

Comment: like I said, not really. you have two different "lengths" to process, which means you should have two different loops. otherwise you waste a ton more lines-of-code on `if()` statements to figure out which x/y is largest, loop on that, then spend more `if()` time skipping over the smaller bit

Comment: @MarcB agreed but I will keep this posted a while. Maybe there is another way that neither of us sees.

Comment: using `std::valarray` you can do it without loops

Comment: @user3528438 Thanks for the tip. Looking over valarray, what I would do is use a lambda with a static incrementer to multiply the incremented static variable by the offset within a function used for apply. Is there something more direct? The approach I'm suggesting seems somewhat convoluted and not very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you feel you must, you could press `std::iota` into service ([live example](http://rextester.com/BFC58863)):

```
class FloatingIota {
public:
  FloatingIota(double start, double inc)
    : start_(start), inc_(inc), n_(0) {}
  FloatingIota& operator++() { ++n_; return *this; }
  operator double() const { return start_ + n_ * inc_; }
private:
  double start_;
  double inc_;
  int n_;
};

std::iota(m_xVals, m_xVals + (xBins+1), FloatingIota(xMin, xInc));
std::iota(y_xVals, m_yVals + (yBins+1), FloatingIota(yMin, yInc));
```

I'll leave it to you to decide to what extent this is "more succint", as such things are in the eye of the beholder.